# What does 0.0_p2 mean?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Please explain what does `0.0_p2` and `1.0_p2` mean here.

```
integer , parameter :: sp = kind(1.0)
integer , parameter :: p2 = selected_real_kind(2*precision(1.0_sp))

real(p2), parameter :: zero = 0.0_p2, &
                       one = 1.0_p2
```

Comment: please clarify exactly what is your problem

Comment: I removed the tag fortran77, the code is incompatible with this aancient standard. Always use the generic tag [tag:fortran] in any Fortran question and add a specific version only when necessary (here it probably is not).

Answer (score 1):

The term

```
0.0_p2
```

is the real number `0.0` with kind `p2`. The snippet you've posted tells us that `p2` denotes the kind returned by the expression

```
selected_real_kind(2*precision(1.0_sp))
```

so `p2` is probably the same as `double precision`, and also probably a 64-bit real number.